# Intellij IDEA language injection in .feature file

Tags: intellij-idea, cucumber, gherkin, cucumber-java

I have a Cucumber scenario defined in `.feature` file in which I test an API I developed:

```
Given Something
When an API call is executed: GET '/v1/my/endpoint'
Then response status is OK
And response body is:
"""
{
  "id": "id-1",
  "message": "it worked"
}
"""
```

I would like to be able to have syntax highlighting for the JSON snippets.
Didn't find anything in docs [1](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/using-language-injections.html) [2](https://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2009/03/user-defined-language-injection/). Language injection comments also doesn't work:

```
# language=javascript
And response body is:
"""
{
  "id": "id-1",
  "message": "it worked"
}
"""
```

So the question is how to make language injection work in `.feature` file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This feature is [not supported](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-137625) at the moment, feel free to vote.